# Should problems with coding when modding a game be in Stack Overflow or Game Development?

Tags: discussion

I have a lot of coding problems when trying to make a mod for the game Minecraft. My question is, **should my questions be in Stack Overflow, or Game Development?**

Comment: Not at Stack Overflow because you looking for debugging help.

Comment: It's possible that such questions could be suitable for either side, but you're more likely to get useful feedback from a site with a closer focus.

Comment: What is your goal? To fuel the site with a helpful question and a possible answer for you and others, or to get help quickly? In this case I'm thinking it is primarily to get help, and the stack sites are not designed for that purpose. If you want support, you should find a place where Minecraft modders congregate which is probably not on any stack site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on what you're asking.  Bear in mind that there could be a question with overlap in one or more sites, so it's always a good idea to pick which one is best.

If you're asking about [anything that's permissible in the Gamedev.SE site](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), such as:

- Game design
- Asset pipelines
- Game-specific programming issues (and I'm sure that there's a finer bead on this when you get into the meat of asking questions)

...then you'd do fine asking it over there.

If you're asking about [anything that's permissible on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), such as:

- A specific programming problem
- Tools used by programmers
- An algorithm

...then you'd do fine asking it here.

Bear in mind, if your request is tantamount to, "This isn't working, please help!", I doubt that it will find a home on either side.  Be sure that you've done all you can to figure out the issue, and provide whomever you're asking with enough details so that you could be helped out.